# "SequelizeValidationError: notNull Violation" en una propiedad que no debería existir

Tags: sequelize.js, pruebas-unitarias

Estoy escribiendo pruebas unitarias para un servidor de nodo que utiliza Sequelize. Al insertar algunos datos falsos estoy recibiendo el error

```
SequelizeValidationError: notNull Violation: QuestionId cannot be null
```

**Notar la Q mayúscula en el `QuestionId`**

prueba:

```ts
describe('answerQuestion', () => {
    it('debe insertar una respuesta y conseguir la siguiente pregunta', (done) => {
        Survey.DBModel.create({lookType: 0}, {logging: false}).then(() => {
            Question.DBModel.create({type: 0, text: 'Test question'}, {logging: false}).then(q1 => {
                Question.DBModel.create({type: 1, text: 'Next question'}, {logging: false}).then(q2 => {
                    console.log('antes');
                    QuestionOption.DBModel.create({text: 'Test option', questionId: 1, nextQuestionId: 2}, {logging: false}).then(() => {
                        console.log('despues');
                        Survey.answerQuestion(1, 1, 1).then(question => {
                            question.should.have.property('id');
                        }, done);
                    }, done);
                }, done);
            }, done);
        }, done);
    });
});
```

Las salidas de la consola "antes", pero los errores antes de que llega "después"

question.js

```js
'use strict';
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var Question = sequelize.define('Question', {
    id: {
      allowNull: false,
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true,
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER
    },
    type: {
      allowNull: false,
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER
    },
    text: {
      allowNull: false,
      type: DataTypes.STRING
    },
    nextQuestionId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER
    }
  }, {
    classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {
        models.Question.belongsTo(models.Question, {as: 'nextQuestion', foreignKey: {field: 'nextQuestionId', allowNull: true}});
        models.Question.hasMany(models.Answer, {as: 'answers', foreignKey: {field: 'questionId', allowNull: false}});
        models.Question.hasMany(models.QuestionOption, {as: 'options', foreignKey: {field: 'questionId', allowNull: false}});
        models.Question.hasMany(models.QuestionOption, {as: 'referrers', foreignKey: {field: 'nextQuestionId', allowNull: true}});
      }
    }
  });
  return Question;
};
```

questionoption.js

```js
'use strict';
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var QuestionOption = sequelize.define('QuestionOption', {
    id: {
      allowNull: false,
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true,
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER
    },
    questionId: {
      allowNull: false,
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER
    },
    text: {
      allowNull: false,
      type: DataTypes.STRING
    },
    nextQuestionId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER
    }
  }, {
    classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {
        models.QuestionOption.belongsTo(models.Question, {as: 'question', foreignKey: {field: 'questionId', allowNull: false}});
        models.QuestionOption.belongsTo(models.Question, {as: 'nextQuestion', foreignKey: {field: 'nextQuestionId', allowNull: true}});
      }
    }
  });
  return QuestionOption;
};
```

Estos modelos son bastante fuertemente acoplados entre sí y tienen un autorreferencial y todo tipo de casos. Todos los demás modelos que siento no son relevantes para esto, pero se puede proporcionar si es necesario.

Ejecutar SQL en la base de datos SQLite directamente, en el mismo orden y con las mismas propiedades que las sentencias CREATE anterior no una excepción, ya través de muchas pruebas.

Es evidente que Sequelize no intenta ejecutar la sentencia de creación de `QuestionOption`. Errores antes de generar el SQL para ejecutar.

Algunos comportamientos extraños son que las asociaciones son meticulosamente definidas en los modelos y todas ellas tienen un *caso menor* `q` para `questionId` en sus definiciones. Todas las asociaciones tienen también una asociación inversa definida, por lo Sequelize no debería tratar de crear nombres de propiedades.

Todas las tablas se borran y vuelven a crear antes de cada prueba (con éxito).

Agregando a la evidencia de que algo raro está pasando es que si me quito el `questionId: 1` de la sentencia de creación de QuestionOption, se convierte entonces en el error

```
SequelizeValidationError: notNull Violation: questionId cannot be null, 
notNull Violation: QuestionId cannot be null
```

Tenga en cuenta del caso de ambos, uno es menor (el que yo eliminé) y uno es mayor.

Siguiente sospechoso es el asociación `nextQuestionId`, pero se ha definido en el modelo, y cada lado de la asociación como`allowNull: true` *y* he proporcionado en la sentencia de creación.

Estoy puramente desconcertado en este comportamiento y cuestionando si esto tal vez es un bug en Sequelize, aunque yo tendría que confirmarlo antes de reportarlo falsamente.

Otra información que tal vez podría ser útil es:

- Las pruebas se ejecutan mediante el comando `NODE_ENV = test mocha`
- La creación de base de datos para las pruebas es automática usando `sync` (código abajo)
- Todas las otras pruebas pasan, pero este es el único que utiliza QuestionOption en la prueba.
- El método que estoy tratando de probar funciona "en producción" (que se ejecuta localmente en dev con el cliente conectado)
- Esquema de base de datos ha sido verificada con una SQLite GUI y todas las columnas son apropiadas (No hay field `QuestionId` en cualquier table con un Q de letra mayúscula)

La creación de bases de datos para las pruebas

```ts
beforeEach((done) => {
    Survey.DBModel.sync({force: true, logging: false}).then(() => {
        Question.DBModel.sync({force: true, logging: false}).then(() => {
            Answer.DBModel.sync({force: true, logging: false}).then(() => {
                QuestionOption.DBModel.sync({force: true, logging: false}).then(() => {
                    done();
                }, done);
            }, done);
        }, done);
    }, done);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No me gusta responder preguntas de las cuales no domino, (y no entiendo como explicar), pero como veo que esta pregunta se formulo hace algun tiempo intentare ponerle cual puede ser el error y su solucion.

Pruebe a cambiar esta linea:

```
QuestionOption.DBModel.create({text: 'Test option', questionId: 1,
                              nextQuestionId: 2}, {logging: false}).then(() => {
```

por esta:

```
QuestionOption.DBModel.create({text: 'Test option', questionId: 1, 
                              QuestionId: 1 ,
                              nextQuestionId: 2}, {logging: false}).then(() => {
```

Puedes ver que se ha añadido QuestionId: 1,

Una vez alguien soluciono un error igual en un codigo distinto, especificando el argumento dentro de la función que devolvia, asi que creo que quizas lo anterior le ayude.